# EmberJS - Computed headers value not called

Tags: ember.js

In my Ember app I have subclassed RESTAdapter in order to dynamically update the authorisation headers for each request sent to my api:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import Ember from 'ember';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    user: Ember.inject.service(),
    host: 'https://occasions-wjdhamilton.c9.io',
    headers: Ember.computed(function() {
        this.get('user').getAuthHeaders();
    }),
    handleResponse(status, headers, payload) {
        if (headers['access-token']) {
            this.get('user').setToken(headers['access-token']);
        }
        return this._super(status, headers, payload);
    }
});
```

However, the computed function does not get called and I cannot work out why. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify which properties you're going to use to compute the headers by passing 'user' in, and you're also missing a `return`:

```
headers: Ember.computed('user', function() {
  return this.get('user').getAuthHeaders();
}),
```

I think that should work.

Comment: Bingo! Thanks for your help!